# Swift - How to retrieve multiple values from Firebase and display them on UITABLEVIEW

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase

This is the structure of my database. I store each event with uuid as its unique identifier under the root node "events".

```
events:
     uuid:
        name: summer festival 2017
        site: vegas
        participants:
           employeeID1: true
           employeeID2: true
```

I have a UITableview that has 3 columns and I want this table to display the following data

```
Colum1(event name)       Column2(site)          Column2(# of Participants) 
summer festival 2017     vegas                  2000
```

I tried this block of code but it won't work. Please help.

```
let myRef = ref?.child("events")

myRef?.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                if let eventName = snap.value["name"] as String {
                    self.events.append(eventName)
                }
            }

        })
```

Comment: you want to get all data in one mechanism of databaseHandler and display in TableView all at once ?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. Yes, is it possible and if yes, how do I do that?

Comment: please do not make use of query if you want all data in once just get all the events in database handler and sort it later on I did in my chat app should I show you some Demo for it ?

Comment: Yes please, I'm new to Firebase and I don't know how to implement the codes.

Comment: okay please wait

Comment: you just want to display event name in tableView ? all at once ?

Comment: i want to display all the data in the 3 columns i created. event name, site and # of participants. In the code above i tried to display the event name first just to see if it works but it didn't

Comment: check my answer as you want to get all the three at once get all those in arrays from for loop as count will be same so use any of them as return parameter and further display them in tableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is code you can try. Hope it Helps!

```
//TableView outlet
@IBOutlet weak var namesTable: UITableView!

//Array to save all event Names
var names = [String]()

//Database handler Object
var readData = DatabaseReference()

//I use a separate Dictionary to take snapshot out of handler if required
var postData = [String:AnyObject]()

//make use of serrate function or calling didLoad 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//Database reference to Fetch Data
readData = Database.database().reference()

//here is a databaseHandler which fetch all events data at once
    self.databaseHandler = self.readData.child("events").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.postData = ((snapshot.value) as? [String : AnyObject]!)!

        //print data to see if you require 
        //print it to generate loop for required things
        print(self.postData)

        //make snapshot as [string:anyobject]
        if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            ////here is a loop which will run after you get your snapshot
            for each in snapDict{
                 //you will get all your names in a array all at once
                let artistName = each.value["name"] as! String

                //use this array to save all event name
                self.names.append(artistName)

            }
            //remove ypur datasource and delegate from Storyboard
            //here you can provide datasource and delegate
            //if on same controller you have multiple functionality 
            //write reload table line here with datasource and delegate
            self.namesTable.dataSource = self
            self.namesTable.delegate = self
        }
    })
}
```

TableView Delegates

```
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
{
    return names.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = self.namesTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: if still face any issue please let me know

Comment: Thank you iOS Geek. I'll try this out

Comment: You're a genius. it worked. Thank you so much! I'm so happy :)

Comment: Welcome. Happy to Help :)